# While loop for except ValueError, not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_number():
    x = True
    while x == True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            if x < 1 :
                raise ValueError('Invalid input, please enter a number above 0: ')   # go to except block
        except ValueError:
            print ("Invalid input, please enter an integer: ")
            get_number()

get_number()
```

If you type -1 then a ValueError for example "x" multiple times, then you type in a correct number like 5, it takes multiple tries until the code takes it in a correct.

Comment: take input no to other variable then x as you are already using it , also dont call get_number again

Comment: Sorry, I am more of a visual learner, could you please type the code instead?

Comment: Can you please explain more about what is wrong with your program?

Comment: change `x==True` to `y==True` and all tace of it and also remove `get_number`

Comment: @KaziSohan if you enter a number lower than 0, like -1, or enter a character other than an integer, like A or B or C, etc, multiple times, then enter a correct number like 5, you need to type it many times until the program stops.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Oh silly me, I just realised what I had done, sorry, mainly a sugar crash, never eating cake in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if the user enters `1` as their input, the while loop will continue because in python `1 == True` is a true statement.

On errors you call `get_number` again which is unnecessary because you are already in a while loop - you should decide to either use recursion or a loop here.

In my code I store the user input in a different variable to get rid off issues of 1 == True

```py
def get_number():
    x = True
    while x == True:
        try :
            i = int(input("Enter number: "))
            if i<1:
                raise ValueError("Number must be higher than 1")
            else:
                # User has inputted valid number
                x = False   
                return i
    
        except ValueError:
            print("Your input must be greater than 1 and an integer")
```

Because I'm no longer using x as the user input, we need to break out of the loop at some time. I set x to False **and** returned from the function which is not needed, you can just return, but you didn't include that part in your code so I leave it up to you what to do in  the case of success.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the first x. Instead, you can do this. And also remove the recursion call of the function

```
def get_number():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            if x < 1 :
                raise ValueError('Invalid input, please enter a number above 0: ')   # go to except block
        except ValueError:
            print ("Invalid input, please enter an integer: ")

get_number()
```

Comment: There is more to the code (hence why I have to declare the first x, but I changed it to y, as I realised that I was using x for the user's input, but the rest is correct.